# Tensorflow 1.14: tf.numpy_function loses shape when mapped?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

This code is mostly based off of the TF GUide [Load images with `tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#a_dataset_of_image_label_pairs).

Here is the modified [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DeGMPxb8cyHm5QLpqJ9-cB2sbF8PC3vA#scrollTo=qGiGN5rl4s2f&line=22&uniqifier=1) with the error.

The first change in the code is harmless:

```py
# resize is moved to be an argument
def preprocess_image(image, resize=[192, 192]):
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, resize)
  image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range

  return image

# argument bubbled up 
def load_and_preprocess_image(path, resize=[192, 192]):
  image = tf.read_file(path)
  return preprocess_image(image, resize)
```

the next change is where the issue is introduced:

```
# from tf, with above modifications, works fine
image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

# error comes here

# dataset only contains paths, so wrap whatever value for `resize` in lambda
_load_and_preprocess_image = lambda path: load_and_preprocess_image(path, [192,192])

# we "have" numpy functionality for handling images so wrap in `tf.numpy_function`
tf_load_and_preprocess_image = lambda path: tf.numpy_function(_load_and_preprocess_image, [path], tf.float32)

# shape is lost
image_ds2_error_boogaloo = path_ds.map(tf_load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

# no shape
image_ds2_error_boogaloo
# `<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: , types: tf.float32>`
```

how can I get around this? `tf.numpy_function` doesn't have an argument to specifically defined shapes and `tf.data.Dataset`'s property `output_shapes` is read only

Answer (score 0):

Try using tf.reshape just after the tf.numpy_function to reinitialize shapes.

```
image = tf.read_file(path)
image_shape = tf.shape(image)
numpy_func = lambda image: some_numpy_function(image)
image = tf.numpy_function(numpy_func, [image], tf.float32)
image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
```

Comment: This is does not work in a map function of a tf.data.Dataset as the question states.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a `tf.numpy_function` wrapping a function working on numpy arrays rather than tensors, where autograph complained that the output of the function had an unknown shape.

Using tf.reshape as proposed by Kutay YILDIZ did the trick, here is the code snippet:

```
def foo_numpy(image_numpy):
    # your code here
    return image_numpy

def foo_tensor(image_tensor):
    result = tf.numpy_function(foo_numpy, [image_tensor], tf.float32)
    result = tf.reshape(result, image_tensor.shape)
    return result

@tf.function
def process_image(image_tensor):
   image_tensor = foo_tensor(image_tensor) # autograph still knows the size of image_tensor
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31373#issuecomment-524666365) answer I think it could be useful.

> Note that you can also restore shapes lost due to applying a numpy_function through `map(lambda x: tf.set_shape(x, ...)`